# Correct definition form class

Tags: php

i have class

```
class Form {

public function addTextarea(array $par){

$element='. $par['label'] .';
$element .= '<textarea name="'. $par['name'] .'" id="'.  $par['id'] .'" cols="'.  $par['cols'] .'" rows="'.  $par['rows'] .'" class="' $par['class'] '"></textarea>'  ;
return $element;

}

// another form elements

}

$tab1 = array (
    'name'=>'newsletter',
    'id'=>'nwsltr',
    'cols'=>'10',
    'rows'=>'5',
    'class'=>'newsletter',
    'label'=>'Subscribe',   
    'value'=> $_POST['email']
);


    $ob->new Form;
    print $ob->addTextarea($tab1);
```

Did this pattern is good ? How i  can simple write array, another write class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is better

```
<?php 
class Form { 

    public function addTextarea(array $par){ 
        $element = $par['label']; 
        $element .= '<textarea name="'. $par['name'] .'" id="'.  $par['id'] .'" cols="'.  $par['cols'] .'" rows="'.  $par['rows'] .'" class="'. $par['class']. '"></textarea>'; 
        return $element; 

    } 
} 

$tab1 = array ( 
    'name'=>'newsletter', 
    'id'=>'nwsltr', 
    'cols'=>'10', 
    'rows'=>'5', 
    'class'=>'newsletter', 
    'label'=>'Subscribe',    
    'value'=> $_POST['email'] 
); 


$ob = new Form; 
print $ob->addTextarea($tab1);
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/fcd58.php